# Magento 2 : How to add value to shipping address from

Tags: magento2, ajax, knockoutjs, shipping-address

I am facing issue to add Dynamic value (Via Ajax) in shipping address I was trying to do so with JQuery but validations are failing But my text box has dynamic data assigned to it.

please find some screenshot for your reference.
Value is present in the text box but still required validation error

[image: Value is present in text box but still required validation error]

Comment: How did you assign address data after calling ajax? You try to assign ajax address response to address object. something like address.firstname =  response.firstname

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response i am using JQ code to assign text looks like this   $("input[name='firstname']").val("frist name");

Comment: Try to put all three or any of them  `$("input[name='firstname']").trigger("change");`
`$("input[name='firstname']").keyup();`  
`$("input[name='firstname']").blur();` after assigning the value.